# Placing selectors in variables

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to wrap all of the selectors in my jQuery script inside variables to make it easier to edit and to speed up the script. However I've hit a bit of a snag.

When I use the following code:

```
var docu = $(document);

docu.ready(function(){

  if (status == 'confirm'){
    $('#login').hide();
    }

});
```

everything works fine. However, if I do the following (which is what I'm trying to achieve) the `hide()` function does not work and the `#login` div is still visible.

```
var docu = $(document);
var loginElement = $('#login');

docu.ready(function(){

  if (status == 'confirm'){
    loginElement.hide();
  }

});
```

I've checked that the `status` variable is being set correctly, so it seems to be a problem with the `loginElement` variable. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Place it within the document ready.

Comment: Does it work when using `$('#login').hide();` instead?

Comment: Place this `var loginElement = $('#login')` inside `docu.ready(function()` and check whether you have more one one element with id `login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var docu = $(document);
var loginElement = $('#login');

docu.ready(function(){

  if (status == 'confirm'){
    loginElement.hide();
  }

});
```

Every thing but one is fine .. THINK .. Is it possible to get an JQuery DOM Object before document ready....????? I think you got the answer.

```
 var docu = $(document);
    docu.ready(function(){
     var loginElement = $('#login');
      if (status == 'confirm'){
        loginElement.hide();
      }

    });
```

Do this will work

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you create the loginElement, when the document is not yet ready. I suggest you to do the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

var docu = $(document);
var loginElement = $('#login');
  if (status == 'confirm'){
    loginElement.hide();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery is very DOM-Orieneted, it relies heavily on the `$(document).ready` binding. Event binding code running before the DOM is ready will not be bound.

That's why you have to place this assignment:

```
var loginElement = $('#login');
```

Inside the `document.ready` as well, otherwise it can't find the element matching `#login`.